# How to authenticate with Evernote developer account with OAuth.io

Tags: javascript, html, evernote

I have a task to create **SPA that will be using Evernote account data**. For authetication I want to use **Oauth.io service**. 
"Try auth" button from Oauth.io site works fine. I see popup with prompt to sign in.

In my app html I have a simple button:

```
<button id="login-evernote-btn" type="button" class="bx-button bx-button-accept" onclick="app.loginWithEvernote();"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Evernote Login</button>
```

and my JS application:

```
//Constructor
function Application() {
    OAuth.initialize('HERE_PASTE_MY_PUBLIC_KEY');
};

/*----------------------------*/
/*    Application methods     */
/*----------------------------*/

Application.prototype.loginWithEvernote = function() {

    OAuth.popup('evernote', function(error, success){

    });
};

// Create application Object
app = new Application();
```

But after clicking on my button I see splash window that closing in second. I can't enter  my credentials.

What step I am doing wrong?

After successful authetication I want to use Evernote API to list all notes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to log the error to see what is the problem with the popup. That maybe the domain whitelist or using 'evernote' provider instead of 'evernote_sandbox'

According [evernote-sdk-js](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js#example) on github, you can use your token this way

```
Application.prototype.loginWithEvernote = function() {
    OAuth.popup('evernote').done(function(evernote) {

        var client = new Evernote.Client({token: evernote.oauth_token});
        var noteStore = client.getNoteStore();
        notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks(function(err, notebooks) {
           // run this code
        });

    }).fail(function(e) {
        console.error(e)
    });
};
```